# Like and dislike buttons for every post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Guys I just created like/dislike buttons for every service! so I set a default grey color for each one of them, once the user click " like" it turns to green and for the opposite case it turns to red..

so I've created an ajax method for that...

I wanted to check if everything works fine  with a simple alert()
but I got an error which is :

> message: "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquen\Builder::$like",…}
>   exception : "ErrorException"
>   — file : "C:\xampp\htdocs\dawerelzirou\app\Http\Controllers\ServiceController.php"
>   — line:164
>   message: "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$like"
>   trace : [
>   —  { file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\dawerelzirou\app\Http\Controller\ServiceController.php", line: 164 }
>   ]

**This is like.js**

```
$('.like').on('click', function() {
  var like_s = $(this).attr('data-like');
  var service_id = $(this).attr('data-serviceid');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {
      like_s: like_s,
      service_id: service_id,
      _token: token
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert('ok');
    }
  });
});
```

**This is the script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/like.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var url="{{ route('like') }}";
   var token="{{ Session::token() }}";
</script>
```

**Here is the blade page :**

```
@php 
$like_count=0;
$dislike_count=0;
$like_statut="grey";
$dislike_statut="grey";
@endphp

@foreach ($services->likes as $like)
  @php
    if ($like->like ==1){
      $like_count++;
    }
    else {
      $dislike_count++;
    }
    if($like->like == 1 && $like->user_id==Auth::user()->id){
      $like_statut="green";
    }
    else{
      $dislike_statut="red";
    }
  @endphp
@endforeach

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <button type="button"
      data-like="{{$like_statut}}"
      data-serviceid="{{$services->id}}"
      class="like waves-effect waves-light btn {{$like_statut}}"> 
        <i class="material-icons left">thumb_up</i>({{$like_count}})
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <button type="button"
      data-dislike="{{$dislike_statut}}"
      class="dislike waves-effect waves-light btn {{$dislike_statut}}"> 
        <i class="material-icons left">thumb_down</i>({{ $dislike_count}})
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**The route:**

```
Route::post('/like','ServiceController@like')->name('like');
```

**The "like" method in the controller:**

```
public function like(Request $request)
{
  $like_s = $request->like_s;
  $service_id = $request->service_id;
  $like = Like::where(['service_id' => $service_id, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id, ]);
  if (!$like) {
    $new_like = new Like;
    $new_like->service_id = $service_id;
    $new_like->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $new_like->like = 1;
    $new_like->save();

  } elseif ($like->like == 1) {
    Like::where(['service_id' => $service_id, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,])
      ->delete()
    ;

  } elseif ($like->like == 0) {
    Like::where(['service_id' => $service_id, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,])
      ->update(array('like' => 1))
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Which is line 164? Error message tells you exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This row:

```
$like = Like::where(['service_id' => $service_id, 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id, ]);
```

seems incomplete, as it returns a query builder and not an object. The query builder has not a "like" property. If you want an object you should do: A `first()` at the end (or a `get()` followed by a `foreach`) seems to be missing.